# Consistency strength of $\aleph_2$-Souslin hypothesis

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory

**Question 1.** What is known about the consistency strength of $\aleph_2$-Souslin hypothesis?

**Question 2.** What is known about the consistency strength of having both $\aleph_2$-Souslin hypotheis and $\aleph_3$-Souslin hypothesis?

**Remark 1.** By $\kappa$-Souslin hopothesis, I mean there are no $\kappa$-Souslin trees.

**Remark 2.** By Laver-Shelah, the existence of a weakly compact cardinal implies the consistency of  $\aleph_2$-Souslin hypothesis. On the other hand by results of Shelah-Stanly, if we assume some instances of $GCH$+ $\aleph_2$-Souslin hypothesis (having $CH$ is sufficient), then some large cardinals (at least Mahlo) are required. In the above question I do not take care of preserving instances of $GCH$.

Answer (score 11):

Answer to 1, without CH:

- Mitchell and Silver, 1973: Weakly compact is an upper bound.

Answer to 1, with CH:

- Laver and Shelah, 1981: Weakly compact is an upper bound.
- Shelah and Stanley, 1982: Inaccessible is a lower bound.

Answer to 1, with GCH:

- Gregory, 1976: Mahlo cardinal is a lower bound.
- Rinot, 2016: Weakly compact is a lower bound.

Answer to 2, with GCH:

- Rinot, 2016 (building on recent work of Schindler and Steel): AD
  holds in $L(\mathbb R)$ is a lower bound.

Comment: my paper is available here: http://www.assafrinot.com/paper/24

Comment: Very nice Assaf. I'm still wondering what happens if we assume no $GCH$ type assumptions.